# MySQL query running slow - email opens sorted by Email Provider

Tags: mysql

The following view goes through a table with about 12M records, identifies which one fall within the top 7 email providers (gmail/yahoo etc) and then groups the results by the email_id (the email that it applies to) and the domains.

The problem is that it's very very slow... and has become unusable.

Are there any suggestions on optimizing/improving it?

```
   DELIMITER $$

ALTER ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`core_usr`@`%` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `email_opens_by_provider` AS (
SELECT
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(`email_stats`.`email_address`,'@',-(1)) AS `domain`,
  SUM(`email_stats`.`is_read`) AS `SUM(is_read)`,
  COUNT(0)                    AS `email_count`,
  `email_stats`.`email_id` AS `email_id`
FROM `email_stats`
WHERE ((SUBSTRING_INDEX(`email_stats`.`email_address`,'@', - (1))IN('gmail.com','yahoo.com','hotmail.com','aol.com','comcast.net','msn.com','outlook.com')))
GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(`email_stats`.`email_address`,'@', - (1)),`email_stats`.`email_id`)$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Yes, I imagine multiple substring_index operations against 12 million rows would be very slow. Do you have any control over the tables here, specifically, can you add a column to store the email domain so you can save a lot of substringing in the view?

Comment: @EatPeanutButter - I do have control over the table... would I substring through and store the domain separately, and then run essentially the same function, but using the new column without the substring_index?

Comment: Yes, something like that. Maybe run a job nightly to extract the domains into a new column and rebuild indexes on that column. That should give you a pretty significant performance bump. Another option is to create an extract of this data in another db that refreshes periodically, but of course you'd need to be OK with slightly out-of-date data.

Comment: @EatPeanutButter

Just an FYI, I have elected to take your approach, using a trigger on DB insert to add the domain in a separate column (thereby eliminating the need for the cron job). I'll post the trigger code here once it's done for the sake of posterity.